# How can I INSERT or UPDATE in Doctrine using a non-primary key

Tags: doctrine

I have a table, with the columns(Id, client_id...)

I need insert or update using the non-primaryKey client_id as unique...

```
if client_id exist
   INSERT.....
else
   UPDATE.....WHERE client_id = X
```

I'm using doctrine, my code is like this

```
$em = getEntityManager();
            $programaFidelidade = new ProgramaFidelidadeClientes;
            $programaFidelidade->setIdCliente($param['idCliente']);
            $programaFidelidade->setIdProgramaFidelidade($param['programa']);

            $em->merge($programaFidelidade);
            $em->flush();
```

My entity is like this:

```
     /**
    * @Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
    * @Id
    * @GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
    */
   private $id;

   /**
    * @Column(name="id_cliente", type="integer")
    */
   private $idCliente;
```

Thanks

Sorry for my English

@EDIT (working code)

```
$programaFidelidade =  $em->getRepository(ProgramaFidelidadeClientes::class)->findBy(['idCliente' => $param['idCliente']]);

            if($programaFidelidade == null){
                $programaFidelidade = new ProgramaFidelidadeClientes;
                $programaFidelidade->setIdCliente($param['idCliente']);
                $programaFidelidade->setIdProgramaFidelidade($param['programa']);
                $em->merge($programaFidelidade);
            }else{
                $programaFidelidade[0]->setIdCliente($param['idCliente']);
                $programaFidelidade[0]->setIdProgramaFidelidade($param['programa']);
                $em->merge($programaFidelidade[0]);
            }
            $em->flush();
            $this->retorno_json(true, true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually I do this:

```
$em = getEntityManager();

$programaFidelidade = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:ProgramaFidelidadeClientes')->find($param['idCliente']);

if (null == $programaFidelidade) {
   $programaFidelidade = new ProgramaFidelidadeClientes;
   $programaFidelidade->setIdCliente($param['idCliente']);
   $programaFidelidade->setIdProgramaFidelidade($param['programa']);

   $em->merge($programaFidelidade);
   $em->flush();
} else {
   $programaFidelidade->setIdCliente($param['idCliente']);
   $programaFidelidade->setIdProgramaFidelidade($param['programa']);

   $em->merge($programaFidelidade);
   $em->flush();
}
```

I have call the repository with name and namespace like this: `AppBundle:ProgramaFidelidadeClientes` but I don't know if in your app there is another bundle or different name.

Comment: I changed a little, but it worked. 

I will add the code i using in the post. Thanks

Comment: Glad to help you @OtavioSouzaRocha